# access form on click open new form with that value with multiple fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have a continuous access form with last name and first name in two separate fields. When the user clicks on either the last name OR the first name, I want VBA to open a new form based on that persons first + last name. I have got VBA working for a single field as follows:

```
private sub namelist_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "newform", , , "last_name = '" & Me.LastName & "'"
End Sub
```

So this will open my new form and will show all the records where the last name is the last name the user clicked on. But the problem is some people share a last name (like Smith). In SQL I would just right where last_name = lastname and first_name = firstname, does anyone know how to do that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's multiple conditions:

```
"last_name = '" & Me.LastName & "' AND " & _
"first_name = '" & Me.FirstName & "'"
```

However, I would assume you would want to **explicitly** know which person they are searching for. First name and last name are simply not accurate enough to define a *single* person.
e.g: There can be 2+ Mary Johnsons, Ken Smith, etc.

I would recommend using an ID or another field that *uniquely identifies each person*, assuming one exists.

Comment: ahhhh thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't get that And " & to work, so hard to understand the syntax.

Comment: No problem! It gets a lot better when you do it a couple times. Just make sure you retain the knowledge so you don't have to keep digging for it over and over. It will save you a lot of time!

Comment: If you don't mind, could you send me a link so I can learn to understand the syntax in these statements? all of the double and single quotes confuse me. I found a microsoft link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845(v=office.15).aspx that says the where clause is EXACTLY like a SQL statement without the where clause, but obviously it's not. Is it because it's a string value?

Comment: I use a couple of different resources. [Allen Browne](http://www.allenbrowne.com/) is a good one. There is a plethora of knowledge to be found there, but it's going to take you a little bit of searching. [This](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) is a good chart when referring to controls of different levels of forms, etc. I have used [this](http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/) website a little, also. It will help with a variety of questions you may/may not have. Hope these help.